# Access ngrok when session is closed

Tags: ngrok

I have installed ngrok on my raspberry pi. How do I keep the tunnel running so I can access it remotely? I am able to access remotely if I have an active SSH session open with ./ngrok http 80.  But as soon as I close that ssh session the tunnel closes. I am a paid member so my address is static.

Comment: Can you try running the ngrok with `nohup ngrok http 80 &`. This will run the ngrok application without console so that once you close terminal the tunnel doesn't close

Comment: Here is what gets returned $ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
nohup: failed to run command 'ngrok': No such file or directory

Comment: Some addition info to @Sashank answer: you need to run `nohup ./ngrok http 80 &` from folder, where ngrok stores. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see the terminal you need to use `nohup` command. It will write all output to a file and you can close the window.

`nohup ./ngrok http 80 &` will start ngrok without terminal.
make sure you use the command from where ngrok is present.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it with the help of [GNU Screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/).

1º After install Screen, I did create a session for ngrok use:

```
$ screen -S ngrok_session
```

2º Then I listed the screen sessions:

```
$ screen -ls
There is a screen on:
    4065.ngrok_session  (06/19/23 17:46:37) (Detached)
```

3º Then I entered that session:

```
$screen -r 4065
```

4º Inside finally I launched ngrok:

```
$ngrok http 49159
```

Then I closed the terminal and ngrok still was running.

Hope it helps.